# Nagios Core to monitor Cisco VPN Tunnel

Tags: vpn, cisco, nagios, check-snmp

I am able to see if a VPN tunnel is up using check_snmp.  The OID for one of my tunnels is .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.3.1.35.3002962.

When the tunnel is up, no problems.  The problem, is when the tunnel is down, because the OID is gone.

working:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H 10.10.10.1 -C public -o .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.3.1.35.3002962
```

returns:

```
SNMP OK - 1 | iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.3.1.35.300296=1

Tunnel down and OID missing:

External command error: Error in packet
Reason: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB.
Failed object: iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.3.1.35.30029
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Looks like I am going to have to write my own.  The OID's for the tunnel change, so using a straight check_snmp won't work.  Still can't find out why the check_asa_vpn add in errors out.

Comment: You might have to write your own script to handle the error.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just ping the IP on the other end of the tunnel?

Comment: before I write a script, I'm hoping for something aleady done.  Pinging an address over the tunnel is an option...  

The check_asa_vpn looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

Seems it is a normal behaviour for OID `.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.3.1.35`

Its value is `INTEGER: 1` when tunnel is up, but this `OID` disappears when tunnel is down.

So your check should handle this : if `OID` is not found then raise an alert because tunnel is down :

http://www.nycnetworkers.com/management/monitor-cisco-asa-vpn-tunnel-state-via-snmp

> Unlike what we think of “up/down”, the value here if present means
>   that the VPN Tunnel is up. If the tunnel is down, this line disappears
>   from the MIB so when you create your poll, if it no longer sees this
>   line you can send out an alert saying the VPN tunnel is down!

---

By the way, you could monitor OID `1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.171.1.2.3.1.7` instead.

This gives the peer of both side of the tunnel : local and remote.

https://www.appliedtrust.com/blog/2009/08/monitoring-site-site-vpns-cisco-asa

> If the peer IP for a configured tunnel isn't listed here, it's down.

Also, there is a ready to go Perl Nagios plugin that uses this OID :
https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-and-Systems-Management/check_asa_vpn/details

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I am working the check_asa_vpn. I can run it from a command line, but get an error within the nagios web interface:

  *ePN /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_asa_vpn.pl: "Use of uninitialized value $Embed::usr::lib::nagios::plugins::check_5fasa_5fvpn_2epl::secondaryPeerIP in string ne at (eval 1) line 149,".


I'm troubleshooting it.